# I call a modal in my index page 10 second after opening the index page. and i use many close button coding in my modal HTML page

Tags: jquery, colorbox

In Head of Index page the css i call

### http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css

In Body of Index page

```
    
            
           
              function openColorBox(){
                $.colorbox({
                  iframe:true,
                  width:"80%",
                  height:"85%",
                  href: "enquiry.html",
                  onLoad: function() {
                    $('#cboxClose').remove();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                      $(window).colorbox.close();
                    }, 250000)
                  }
                });
              }
              function countDown(){
                seconds--
                $("#seconds").text(seconds);
                if (seconds === 0){
                  openColorBox();
                  clearInterval(i);
                }
              }


              var seconds = 10,
                  i = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

Now Please tell me the close button coding for the modal and will return to same index page

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code

```
$('#cboxClose').click(function(){
            parent.$.colorbox.close();
            return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this function to be call in the index file or in the html file that opened after 10 sec?